# Access SQL Select * as OneColumn

Tags: sql

I know that if you want to combine one ore more fields in a dummy field you would say like this.

```
Select Name & ' ' & Surname as FullName from Customer .
```

that would return to the dummy column "FullName" the name separated by space and then surname.

BUT what happen if I want to select all the columns as one column with out needing writing explicitly the name of the column that I want to combine . For example

```
Select * as MyDummyColumn from Customer
```

is there any way to do something like above ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: NO.

Long answer: It depends. In Oracle, for example, I would write a package (or a single procedure) which takes a parameter (tablename), and create a select programmatically, and then use the execute immediate to execute the sql ...

I´m sure, there are similar ways in other db´s.

Or using a programming language like c#, java, vb (.net or even vb6) or whatever there may be, you can generate the sql by code.

Comment: am always afraid the answers to my questions most of the times are always negative : )) how ever am really thank you for your time ,i guess i will go ahead with standart method